# Can you perform the "running start" for a jump at the end of your previous turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

> [Acrobatics: Jumping and Falling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/Acrobatics/#Jumping_and_Falling)
>
> The base DC to make a jump is equal to the distance to be crossed (if
> horizontal) or four times the height to be reached (if vertical).
> These DCs double if you do not have at least 10 feet of space to get a
> running start.

This rubs up against the age old question of "What the heck is temporal continuity in a turn-based RPG?"

If the last action I performed on my turn was moving 10 feet in a direction, would I be considered as having a running start if I wanted to immediately perform a jump in that direction at the start of my next turn?

Comment: There was a disconnect between your title and final question in the body. I rephrased the title, since @Gloweye's answer was phrased in response to the body but it might make more sense to rollback the edit, change your last sentence instead, and coordinate for Gloweye to edit as well. I just wanted to do the least change method for triage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Probably, but up to the DM

There's no ruling about it in the Acrobatics rules, as you found out. Therefore, it's always up to the DM to make a ruling on it.

In this case, there's some supporting statements. For example, on the [Gamemastering](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering) page:

> Storyteller: Among a GM’s most important tasks is imagining and telling engaging stories.

And on the [combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat) page:

> Each round represents 6 seconds in the game world; there are 10 rounds in a minute of combat.

"Each round **represents**" is something I read as "is an abstraction of". That means that while all combatants have their turns, they're not really taking turns, it's just all happening at once and because that's chaos, we order it into turns to clarify to ourselves what's happening.

However, that doesn't mean that story-wise, there's turns. Therefore, a character running to the edge of a chasm and then jumping over it would, at least to me, count as a running start. Though if you want to cast a Standard Action spell before jumping, I'd probably rule against it.

Answer (score -4):

It’s all in the same action. So you must start the jump with a 10 foot move if you want to Lower DC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).